# Is it possible to convert 3D image to 1D vector?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-transformation, data-mining, conv-neural-network

I use the following code to read images:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


def load_image(file):
    img = Image.open(file)
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray(img, dtype="int32")
    return data

data_3d = load_image('cat.jpg')
data_1d = data.reshape(-1)
```

As you can see, I read an image and transform it from 3D to 1D so that it becomes a single row in my dataset, followed by my manual labeling. I understand that convolutional neural network is made to handle imaging efficiently, but I want to create this dataset and apply classification using **fully connected neural network**. My question is, is such transformation from 3D to 1D valid in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is a valid transformation if you are feeding to a fully connected NN.